# Looking to create a visually appealing 10x4 two dimensional array in python for a board game project

Tags: python, arrays

I am very new to python and am attempting to create a board game of sorts for which i need a 2D array of the dimensions 4 x 10.

I have messed around for a while trying to create the array however am stumped on the best way to do it so that in future i will be able to populate the array how i wish.

The main problem lies in presentation, obviously python automatically prints an array as [x, y, z,].

I want to create something more visually appealing, for example:

```
-------------------
|  x  |  y  |  z  |
-------------------
```

sorry if this seems a stupid question i am just clueless on how to go about this and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a code for me question, you should always provide us with all your attempts to solve the problem on your own and possibly with the code.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of ways of doing this. If you're not using any libraries then you can make it into a list of lists.

```
a = [
      [0,3,0,..], #first row
      [1,4,0,..], #second row
      [2,5,0,..], #third row
       ..**strong text**]
a[0][0] = 0
a[1][0] = 1

#a[row][col]=value
```

Another way of doing this is by simply using numpy library and making 2D arrays. This way you can do a bunch of fast and easy calculations on your frame or fading transitions, etc..

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: awesome thank you i got it working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun ... here's something I quickly knocked together to help get you started.

Now, I'm intentionally going to leave this without further explanation, and let you do a bit of research on your own.  :-)

Setup:

```
import numpy as np

# Header.
h = np.arange(10).astype(str)
# Border.
b = ['-']*19
# Values.
m = np.full([4, 10], '0')
```

Print the board:

```
print(' '.join(h))
print(''.join(b))
for i in m:
    print(' '.join(i))
print(''.join(b))
print(' '.join(h))
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
-------------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
-------------------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```